# B2C - Impersonate Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

About the sample "https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/impersonation".

Someone who has already used it, can you comment on how you handled the authentication logs? I noticed in the B2C Logs both the user who is "`Impersonated`" and the user who is "`Impersonator`", I did not find any records that indicate that there was an "`impersonation`" process.

The Token generated in this process is for the "`Impersonator`" user, and has information about him, is it possible to bring information about the "`Impersonated`" user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be nothing official in the logs generated by AAD B2C for this `impersonation`, and AAD B2C does not know the context of your AAD B2C policy. It can only understand that a token is issued for a particular user, not a custom process that allowed it.

What you can do is use App Insights to inject your own custom events to create logs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thank you for your attention Jas